# javax.crypto.BadPaddingException: Decryption error,

Tags: java

Why the bad padding error comes up on decryption and also why does it show some missing argument?? 
I have coded the encryption and decyrption methods but for the zip files, the zip files gets downloaded from the server with encryption but it doesn't execute the decryption process and stucks on the below error, my all the keys are at correct places.Please follow my below code for the reference and please revert if any additional entity require on my side.

DecryptUtil.java

```
public class DecryptUtil {

    private final static Logger LOGGER = LoggerFactory.getLogger(DecryptUtil.class);

    public static byte[] decodeFile(byte[] key, byte[] fileData) {
        SecretKeySpec skeySpec = new SecretKeySpec(key, "AES");
        byte[] decrypted = null;
        try {
            Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES");
            cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, skeySpec);
            decrypted = cipher.doFinal(fileData);
        } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException | NoSuchPaddingException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (InvalidKeyException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IllegalBlockSizeException | BadPaddingException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch(Exception e){
            // for all other exception
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return decrypted;
    }

    public static byte[] decryptSecKeyToBytes(byte[] secretKey, PrivateKey privateKey) {
        byte[] secretKeyBytesDecrypted = null;
        try {
            Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("RSA/ECB/PKCS1Padding");
            cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, privateKey );
            secretKeyBytesDecrypted = cipher.doFinal(secretKey);
        } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException | NoSuchPaddingException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (InvalidKeyException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IllegalBlockSizeException | BadPaddingException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch(Exception e){
            // for all other exception
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return secretKeyBytesDecrypted;
    }

    public static PrivateKey loadPrivateKey() {
        File filePrivateKey = new File(new CommonUtils().getKeyInputDirAbsolute() +  File.separator + UEConstants.PRIVATE_KEY);

        PrivateKey privateKey = null;
        try {
            FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(filePrivateKey);
            DataInputStream dis = new DataInputStream(fis);
            byte[] encodedPrivateKey = new byte[(int) filePrivateKey.length()];
            dis.readFully(encodedPrivateKey);
            dis.close();
            fis.close();

            KeyFactory keyFactory = KeyFactory.getInstance("RSA");
            PKCS8EncodedKeySpec privateKeySpec = new PKCS8EncodedKeySpec(encodedPrivateKey);
            privateKey = keyFactory.generatePrivate(privateKeySpec);
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (InvalidKeySpecException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch(Exception e){
            // for all other exception
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return privateKey;
    }

    public static boolean decryptResource(String encryptedSource, String decryptedDestination){

        try {
            byte[] secretKeyDecrypted = loadSecretKey();
            if(secretKeyDecrypted == null){
                LOGGER.error("Resource decryption failed as Secret key returns null");
                return false;
            }

            LOGGER.debug("Decrypting source file");
            File encryptedSourceFile = new File(encryptedSource);
            byte[] bytesArray = new byte[(int) encryptedSourceFile.length()];
            FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(encryptedSourceFile);
            fis.read(bytesArray);
            fis.close();

            byte[] fileBytes = DecryptUtil.decodeFile(secretKeyDecrypted, bytesArray);
            File decryptedDestinationFile = new File(decryptedDestination);
            if(!FileUtil.createFilrOrDir(decryptedDestinationFile)){
                LOGGER.error("Resource Decryption failed as Invalid Source file path : " + decryptedDestination);
                return false;
            }

            FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(decryptedDestinationFile);
            fos.write(fileBytes);
            fos.close();

        } catch (Exception e) {
            LOGGER.error("Resource Decryption failed ", e);
            return false;
        } 

        return true;
    }

    private static byte[] loadSecretKey() {
        byte[] secretKeyDecrypted = null;
        try {
            LOGGER.debug("Loading SECURE key");
            File key = new File(new CommonUtils().getKeyInputDirAbsolute() +  File.separator + UEConstants.SECRET_KEY);
            FileInputStream readStream = new FileInputStream(key);
            DataInputStream dis = new DataInputStream(readStream);
            byte secretKeyBytes[] = new byte[(int) key.length()];
            dis.readFully(secretKeyBytes);
            dis.close();
            readStream.close();

            LOGGER.debug("Decrypting SECURE key");
            secretKeyDecrypted = DecryptUtil.decryptSecKeyToBytes(secretKeyBytes, DecryptUtil.loadPrivateKey());

        } catch (IOException e) {
            LOGGER.error("Secret Key Load failed ", e);
        } 

        return secretKeyDecrypted;
    }
}
```

Error Logs

```
2018-09-25 14:43:06.556  INFO 8248 --- [ taskExecutor-1] c.userexperior.jobs.service.BatchHelper  : job_id: null, job_status: IN_PROGRESS, message: Step 1 Section 1 started , user_task_id: null
2018-09-25 14:43:06.569  INFO 8248 --- [ taskExecutor-1] c.userexperior.jobs.service.BatchHelper  : job_id: 224, job_status: S3_DOWNLOAD, message: Download zip from s3 : ue testproj-2/ue testproj_version-2/Task-2/1537866670618_35ec4eff226ebf7d_newer_sdk.zip to:B:/Users/amitk/public/ue/resources/zip/input/1537866670618_35ec4eff226ebf7d_newer_sdk.zip, user_task_id: 0
Tue Sep 25 14:43:06 IST 2018 WARN: Establishing SSL connection without server's identity verification is not recommended. According to MySQL 5.5.45+, 5.6.26+ and 5.7.6+ requirements SSL connection must be established by default if explicit option isn't set. For compliance with existing applications not using SSL the verifyServerCertificate property is set to 'false'. You need either to explicitly disable SSL by setting useSSL=false, or set useSSL=true and provide truststore for server certificate verification.
2018-09-25 14:43:08.552  INFO 8248 --- [ taskExecutor-1] c.userexperior.jobs.service.BatchHelper  : job_id: 224, job_status: ZIP_DECRYPTION, message: Zip decryption started, user_task_id: 0
javax.crypto.BadPaddingException: Decryption error
    at sun.security.rsa.RSAPadding.unpadV15(RSAPadding.java:383)
    at sun.security.rsa.RSAPadding.unpad(RSAPadding.java:294)
    at com.sun.crypto.provider.RSACipher.doFinal(RSACipher.java:363)
    at com.sun.crypto.provider.RSACipher.engineDoFinal(RSACipher.java:389)
    at javax.crypto.Cipher.doFinal(Cipher.java:2164)
    at com.userexperior.util.DecryptUtil.decryptSecKeyToBytes(DecryptUtil.java:60)
    at com.userexperior.batchFramework.configuration.CustomItemProcessor.decryptZip(CustomItemProcessor.java:156)
    at com.userexperior.batchFramework.configuration.CustomItemProcessor.process(CustomItemProcessor.java:97)
    at com.userexperior.batchFramework.configuration.CustomItemProcessor.process(CustomItemProcessor.java:34)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.step.item.SimpleChunkProcessor.doProcess(SimpleChunkProcessor.java:126)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.step.item.SimpleChunkProcessor.transform(SimpleChunkProcessor.java:293)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.step.item.SimpleChunkProcessor.process(SimpleChunkProcessor.java:192)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.step.item.ChunkOrientedTasklet.execute(ChunkOrientedTasklet.java:75)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.step.tasklet.TaskletStep$ChunkTransactionCallback.doInTransaction(TaskletStep.java:406)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.step.tasklet.TaskletStep$ChunkTransactionCallback.doInTransaction(TaskletStep.java:330)
    at org.springframework.transaction.support.TransactionTemplate.execute(TransactionTemplate.java:133)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.step.tasklet.TaskletStep$2.doInChunkContext(TaskletStep.java:271)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.scope.context.StepContextRepeatCallback.doInIteration(StepContextRepeatCallback.java:81)
    at org.springframework.batch.repeat.support.TaskExecutorRepeatTemplate$ExecutingRunnable.run(TaskExecutorRepeatTemplate.java:262)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
2018-09-25 14:43:08.656  INFO 8248 --- [       Thread-4] com.userexperior.util.FileUtil           : File is deleted : B:\Users\amitk\public\ue\resources\zip\input\1537866670618_35ec4eff226ebf7d_newer_sdk.zip
2018-09-25 14:43:08.656  INFO 8248 --- [       Thread-4] c.userexperior.jobs.service.BatchHelper  : job_id: 224 ZipFolder clean up done.
2018-09-25 14:43:08.664 ERROR 8248 --- [ taskExecutor-1] c.userexperior.jobs.service.BatchHelper  : job_id: 224, job_status: ZIP_DECRYPTION, message: Step1 Section 1 failed due to Missing argument, version_key: ed8a31a5-c5b2-4f99-be2d-c636dc8c5c8e, task_id: 2, user_task_id: 0

java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Missing argument
    at javax.crypto.spec.SecretKeySpec.<init>(SecretKeySpec.java:93) ~[na:1.8.0_171]
    at com.userexperior.util.DecryptUtil.decodeFile(DecryptUtil.java:33) ~[classes/:na]
    at com.userexperior.batchFramework.configuration.CustomItemProcessor.decryptZip(CustomItemProcessor.java:163) [classes/:na]
    at com.userexperior.batchFramework.configuration.CustomItemProcessor.process(CustomItemProcessor.java:97) [classes/:na]
    at com.userexperior.batchFramework.configuration.CustomItemProcessor.process(CustomItemProcessor.java:34) [classes/:na]
    at org.springframework.batch.core.step.item.SimpleChunkProcessor.doProcess(SimpleChunkProcessor.java:126) [spring-batch-core-3.0.5.RELEASE.jar:3.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.batch.core.step.item.SimpleChunkProcessor.transform(SimpleChunkProcessor.java:293) [spring-batch-core-3.0.5.RELEASE.jar:3.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.batch.core.step.item.SimpleChunkProcessor.process(SimpleChunkProcessor.java:192) [spring-batch-core-3.0.5.RELEASE.jar:3.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.batch.core.step.item.ChunkOrientedTasklet.execute(ChunkOrientedTasklet.java:75) [spring-batch-core-3.0.5.RELEASE.jar:3.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.batch.core.step.tasklet.TaskletStep$ChunkTransactionCallback.doInTransaction(TaskletStep.java:406) [spring-batch-core-3.0.5.RELEASE.jar:3.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.batch.core.step.tasklet.TaskletStep$ChunkTransactionCallback.doInTransaction(TaskletStep.java:330) [spring-batch-core-3.0.5.RELEASE.jar:3.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.transaction.support.TransactionTemplate.execute(TransactionTemplate.java:133) [spring-tx-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.batch.core.step.tasklet.TaskletStep$2.doInChunkContext(TaskletStep.java:271) [spring-batch-core-3.0.5.RELEASE.jar:3.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.batch.core.scope.context.StepContextRepeatCallback.doInIteration(StepContextRepeatCallback.java:81) [spring-batch-core-3.0.5.RELEASE.jar:3.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.batch.repeat.support.TaskExecutorRepeatTemplate$ExecutingRunnable.run(TaskExecutorRepeatTemplate.java:262) [spring-batch-infrastructure-3.0.5.RELEASE.jar:3.0.5.RELEASE]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149) [na:1.8.0_181]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624) [na:1.8.0_181]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) [na:1.8.0_181]

2018-09-25 14:43:08.951  INFO 8248 --- [ taskExecutor-1] c.userexperior.jobs.service.BatchHelper  : job_id: null, job_status: IN_PROGRESS, message: Step 1 Section 1 started , user_task_id: null
2018-09-25 14:43:08.951  INFO 8248 --- [ taskExecutor-1] c.userexperior.jobs.service.BatchHelper  : job_id: 225, job_status: S3_DOWNLOAD, message: Download zip from s3 : ue testproj-2/ue testproj_version-2/Task-2/1537866693171_35ec4eff226ebf7d_newer_sdk.zip to:B:/Users/amitk/public/ue/resources/zip/input/1537866693171_35ec4eff226ebf7d_newer_sdk.zip, user_task_id: 0
2018-09-25 14:43:09.306  INFO 8248 --- [ taskExecutor-1] c.userexperior.jobs.service.BatchHelper  : job_id: 225, job_status: ZIP_DECRYPTION, message: Zip decryption started, user_task_id: 0
javax.crypto.BadPaddingException: Decryption error
    at sun.security.rsa.RSAPadding.unpadV15(RSAPadding.java:383)
    at sun.security.rsa.RSAPadding.unpad(RSAPadding.java:294)
    at com.sun.crypto.provider.RSACipher.doFinal(RSACipher.java:363)
    at com.sun.crypto.provider.RSACipher.engineDoFinal(RSACipher.java:389)
    at javax.crypto.Cipher.doFinal(Cipher.java:2164)
    at com.userexperior.util.DecryptUtil.decryptSecKeyToBytes(DecryptUtil.java:60)
    at com.userexperior.batchFramework.configuration.CustomItemProcessor.decryptZip(CustomItemProcessor.java:156)
    at com.userexperior.batchFramework.configuration.CustomItemProcessor.process(CustomItemProcessor.java:97)
    at com.userexperior.batchFramework.configuration.CustomItemProcessor.process(CustomItemProcessor.java:34)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.step.item.SimpleChunkProcessor.doProcess(SimpleChunkProcessor.java:126)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.step.item.SimpleChunkProcessor.transform(SimpleChunkProcessor.java:293)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.step.item.SimpleChunkProcessor.process(SimpleChunkProcessor.java:192)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.step.item.ChunkOrientedTasklet.execute(ChunkOrientedTasklet.java:75)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.step.tasklet.TaskletStep$ChunkTransactionCallback.doInTransaction(TaskletStep.java:406)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.step.tasklet.TaskletStep$ChunkTransactionCallback.doInTransaction(TaskletStep.java:330)
    at org.springframework.transaction.support.TransactionTemplate.execute(TransactionTemplate.java:133)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.step.tasklet.TaskletStep$2.doInChunkContext(TaskletStep.java:271)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.scope.context.StepContextRepeatCallback.doInIteration(StepContextRepeatCallback.java:81)
    at org.springframework.batch.repeat.support.TaskExecutorRepeatTemplate$ExecutingRunnable.run(TaskExecutorRepeatTemplate.java:262)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
2018-09-25 14:43:09.324 ERROR 8248 --- [ taskExecutor-1] c.userexperior.jobs.service.BatchHelper  : job_id: 225, job_status: ZIP_DECRYPTION, message: Step1 Section 1 failed due to Missing argument, version_key: ed8a31a5-c5b2-4f99-be2d-c636dc8c5c8e, task_id: 2, user_task_id: 0

java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Missing argument
    at javax.crypto.spec.SecretKeySpec.<init>(SecretKeySpec.java:93) ~[na:1.8.0_171]
    at com.userexperior.util.DecryptUtil.decodeFile(DecryptUtil.java:33) ~[classes/:na]
    at com.userexperior.batchFramework.configuration.CustomItemProcessor.decryptZip(CustomItemProcessor.java:163) [classes/:na]
    at com.userexperior.batchFramework.configuration.CustomItemProcessor.process(CustomItemProcessor.java:97) [classes/:na]
    at com.userexperior.batchFramework.configuration.CustomItemProcessor.process(CustomItemProcessor.java:34) [classes/:na]
    at org.springframework.batch.core.step.item.SimpleChunkProcessor.doProcess(SimpleChunkProcessor.java:126) [spring-batch-core-3.0.5.RELEASE.jar:3.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.batch.core.step.item.SimpleChunkProcessor.transform(SimpleChunkProcessor.java:293) [spring-batch-core-3.0.5.RELEASE.jar:3.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.batch.core.step.item.SimpleChunkProcessor.process(SimpleChunkProcessor.java:192) [spring-batch-core-3.0.5.RELEASE.jar:3.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.batch.core.step.item.ChunkOrientedTasklet.execute(ChunkOrientedTasklet.java:75) [spring-batch-core-3.0.5.RELEASE.jar:3.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.batch.core.step.tasklet.TaskletStep$ChunkTransactionCallback.doInTransaction(TaskletStep.java:406) [spring-batch-core-3.0.5.RELEASE.jar:3.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.batch.core.step.tasklet.TaskletStep$ChunkTransactionCallback.doInTransaction(TaskletStep.java:330) [spring-batch-core-3.0.5.RELEASE.jar:3.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.transaction.support.TransactionTemplate.execute(TransactionTemplate.java:133) [spring-tx-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.batch.core.step.tasklet.TaskletStep$2.doInChunkContext(TaskletStep.java:271) [spring-batch-core-3.0.5.RELEASE.jar:3.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.batch.core.scope.context.StepContextRepeatCallback.doInIteration(StepContextRepeatCallback.java:81) [spring-batch-core-3.0.5.RELEASE.jar:3.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.batch.repeat.support.TaskExecutorRepeatTemplate$ExecutingRunnable.run(TaskExecutorRepeatTemplate.java:262) [spring-batch-infrastructure-3.0.5.RELEASE.jar:3.0.5.RELEASE]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149) [na:1.8.0_181]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624) [na:1.8.0_181]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) [na:1.8.0_181]
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read [the help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help), take [the SO tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour), read about [how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), as well as [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/). Lastly learn how to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: I think you should reduce this to a MCVE. Also see [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: `RSAPadding.unpadV15` you either are using wrong key or wrong padding. Are you sure the original encryption is using Pkcs1.5 padding?

Comment: @gusto2  key which i am using is generated at correct path and it is also downloaded from the server with proper encryption and but when it comes to decrypt the key from that path i get this error

Comment: I got the solution for this, you can check the java version you are using as may be not compatible with OS, as in my case i was using java 8 but when i tried to generate the keys from other java version i.e. java 7, the keys were successfully getting decrypted and the encryption/decryption got processed further easily without any bugs...

Comment: Please check my answer for the similar case https://stackoverflow.com/a/75967459/1759063